# Run two interfaces on one network card

Tags: networking, wlan

Is it possible to run two different network interfaces (e.g. being connected to two different wlan-networks) on one card in parallel on linux? If yes, how? If no, why not (I would be glad about a bit technical background).
Update: I read a bit, and found out that it is possible to have several ip addresses assigned to the same network card (http://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-single-network-interface/), but my problem is that I want to be connected to several wlan-networks (one ad-hoc-network and one usual network) in parallel. Is that possible? Due to a lack of a running unix os I am not able to check that.
After request: My current network card is Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230, but my final target is to do that on android, too (I thought that should be possible after android is a modified linux.... But my first approach would be on a usual pc, specs as above)

Comment: Can your network card do it, if not then no. As for multiple ip per interface, that is a different concept.

Comment: Please add to question, the model of network card that you have. Then maybe someone can help.

Comment: @richard: Currently an Advanced-N 6230 from Intel, but my intention is to reuse that on android (after it is based on linux), too.

Comment: Note: Android is not based on Linux: Linux is often mistakenly used to mean Gnu/Linux (a Free (as in freedom) Unix operating system), this site also uses the word that way. Where as Linux is a kernel that is used in this system, and also used in android. Therefore android uses a (modified, though most have those modifications are now in the main line) Linux kernel, but is not based on Gnu/Linux.

Comment: Run `iw phy | sed -n '/^[a-zA-Z]/p;/combinations:/,/:/p'` to see if any of your wifi cards supports connecting to multiple networks. If yes, it should show something like `#{ managed ... } <= N`, where `N` is a number >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, no you can't have a single wireless card authenticated simultaneously with two wireless networks. Adding another IP address wouldn't help if the security settings are all set for one single network, and every wifi card I've ever played with has had that limitation. But if you want to try it, poke around with `wpa_supplicant` (and its config in `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`); you might learn a lot.